# How do I use Font Awesome as a custom font in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui, custom-font

I have followed a number of tutorials in adding a custom font to my SwiftUI package. I have take the following steps:

- Add `Font Awesome 5 Free Solid-900.otf` to my project.
- Made sure that the font is copied and added to the target
- Added the font file names to the `Fonts provided by application` array in `Info.plist`
- Tried to get the font name
- Tried a large number of permutations and combinations for the font name.

I tried the following:

```swift
Text(Text("\u{f071} Danger Will Robinson").font(.custom("Font Awesome 5 Free Regular", size: 20))
```

which is supposed to give me an alert icon, but all I get is a question mark.

Is there a trick to using Font Awesome in this way?

I know there are a few packages available, but I’m trying to learn more about the process itself, and I can’t see that it should be too hard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, I worked it out.

- For MacOS, the `Info.plist` key is: `Application fonts resource path`, *not* as above.
- The next trick is to get the font name.

One method is to install the font, and then check FontBook. The **PostScript name** is the name I need.

The other is to run the following code:

```swift
let fontManager = NSFontManager.shared
let fonts = fontManager.availableFonts
for name in fonts {
    print(name)
}
```

That’s what happens when *all* the tutorials are for iOS, not MacOS.